# Thread return value check permanently

Tags: java, android

I implemented a Runnable and it checks correct if a boolean value turns true.

But i want to return this value to my class where i start the Thread.

I noticed that i can return a value with Future Callables, with them i can just calculate something and return it immediatly but i cant check permanently if the value turns true.

How can i achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

```
public class ResultChecker implements Runnable{
    private DrawView drawView;

    public ResultChecker(DrawView drawView){
        this.drawView = drawView;
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean run = true;
        while(run){
            if(drawView.isNextQuestion()){
                //RETURN VALUE HERE
                run = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: could you try and rephrase that? what do you mean by "check permanently"?

Comment: I mean that i want to check isNextQuestion() until i stop the Thread.
With Future Callables, i can just check it once and get a return value which will be false. But it could turn true while the Thread is alive.. so i want to check it permanently and want to receive the correct result until i finish the Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to poll, then create a method in `ResultChecker` that can be called by the thread that wants the return value.

```
public class ResultChecker implements Runnable{
    private DrawView drawView;
    private volatile Result r;

    public ResultChecker(DrawView drawView){
        this.drawView = drawView;
        this.r = null;
    }

    public Result poll() {
        return r;
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean run = true;
        while(run){
            if(drawView.isNextQuestion()){
                //RETURN VALUE HERE
                r = someObject;
                // once r has been assigned, you cannot touch it again
                // or the object it refers to from this thread because
                // there are no locks
                run = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The poller will poll like this:

```
r = resultChecker.poll();
if(r != null) {
    // we have result
} else {
    // result is not ready
    // try again later
}
```

If you want to return multiple values, you will have to extend this a bit with a queue.

Comment: Mh.. but how should this "try again later" look like? I cant just call the method again, i would have the same problem with that..I have to check it until i leave this activity..

Comment: Yes, you just call it again whenever you want until the result is not null. If I knew a little more about your program I could be more specific. What is it that your Activity needs to do between polls?

Comment: Also, why exactly do you want your Activity to run the ResultChecker in a separate thread instead of in the Activity?

Comment: I have an Activity and a custom View.
In my Custom View i can do some Drag and Drop Action.
And if this Drag and Drop Action is finished, i would prefer to check in my Activity if all Drag and Drop Actions are done. If yes, i want to call an Intent and move on to the next Activity.

Comment: So the user is going to do a bunch of drag and drops, and when they are done, you want your Activity to check the ResultChecker for the result? Is that right? How would you know when the user is done dragging and dropping? Wouldn't the user have to indicate this somehow?

Comment: Yes i have a boolean variable which is set when all drag and drops are finished.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6446/discussion-between-jay-and-krackmoe)

Answer (score 0):

create a handler in the original thread.  then send a message on that handler when you want to return the value; the message can contain an arbitrary object which will be the result.  The handler will execute it's method handleMessage on the original thread, where you can examine the sent message and react to the result.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what do you mean by ** permanent **

What's wrong with this?

```
public Boolean call() { .. do something..
      return bool;        }
```

Comment: Because it checks just once drawView.isNextQuestion() and returns false. But this value can change, and it could get true, so the Thread should check it as long as i dont finish it

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good idea, but You can also try setting a field variable inside the if condition. `if(cond) { use a setter to set a field var here.. }`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the return value back to the original thread:

1. The original thread can periodically poll `ResultChecker` to see if the return value is available.
2. The original thread can block, and `ResultChecker` will wake-up the original thread when it wants to return a value.

If you tell me which method you prefer, I can give you the details.

Comment: But i dont have an original Thread.
I have an Activity in which i start this Thread.

Do you mean i should do a Thread in a Thread?

But i would prefer the first method..

Comment: By "original thread" I meant what ever thread you want the value returned to. I doesn't matter what thread the result is going to. The only thing that matters is that the value is being sent to another thread.

Comment: Ok, can you please tell me how to do it with method Nr.1